# how to use protobuf compile java specifity enum

Tags: java, enums, protocol-buffers

when I use protobuf compile java specifity enum,my enum.proto code:

```
enum QosP{

    AT_MOST_ONCE = 0;
    AT_LEAST_ONCE = 1;
    EXACTLY_ONCE = 2;

    required int32 val = AT_MOST_ONCE.value;
}
```

I always get a error,as follow : Missing numeric value for enum constant. required int32 val always can not compile.plz I need help.

I try to use proto2 and proto3 to compile，and find many document,but solution this problem.

I want to use protobuf comiple java enum, structure is as follow:

```
enum QosP{

    AT_MOST_ONCE = 0;
    AT_LEAST_ONCE = 1;
    EXACTLY_ONCE = 2;

    required int32 val = AT_MOST_ONCE.value;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The enum declaration and usage should be done separately.

First declare the enum as a type:

```
enum QosP {
    AT_MOST_ONCE = 0;
    AT_LEAST_ONCE = 1;
    EXACTLY_ONCE = 2;
}
```

Then use the enum to define the type of a field. A default value can be defined too:

```
message Something {
    QosP val = 1 [default = AT_LEAST_ONCE];
}
```